# Improving mmap/munmap performance on MacOS X

Tags: c, linux, performance, macos, mmap

Running the following C code (a bunch of mmaps and munmaps on a 2GB file) on a MacOS X machine seems to be dramatically slower than on a Linux one.

```
#define BUFSZ 2000000000
static u_char buf[BUFSZ];
....

// Time 10000 mmaps and munmaps from random offsets for various 
// sizes of mapped chunk.
for (msize = 4096; msize <= 1048576; msize *= 16) {
  fd = open("io_benchmark.dat", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd  < 0 ) die("can't open io_benchmark.dat for reading");
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    // Make sure the block to be mapped doesn't start in the
    // last meg.
    offset = (size_t) random() % (BUFSZ - 1048576);
    mblock = femmap(fd, (off_t)offset, (size_t) msize, PROT_READ, 
                    "test block");
    total = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < msize; j++) {
      total += mblock[j];
    }
    femunmap(mblock, (size_t) msize, "test block");
  }
  printf("Elapsed time to mmap and munmap 10000 blocks of %d kB: %.4f sec\n", 
         msize/1024, (time = time_since_last_call()));

  rslt = close(fd);
  if (fd  < 0 ) die("can't close io_benchmark.dat after reading");
}
```

Specifically, comparing two machines

```
CPU     Xeon E3113 dual core @ 3.00GHz           Core 2 Duo @ 2.4GHz dual core
RAM     8GB                                      4GB
Kernel  2.6.18-92.el5PAE SMP i686                MacOS 10.6.4 Snow Leopard
Disk    WD 250GB SATA 16MB cache 7200 RPM EXT3   Hitachi 250GB SATA 5400 RPM, journaled HFS+
```

Gives the following results

```
                            Linux    MacOS X
Time for 10000 4kB mmaps    0.0165   682.87
Time for 10000 64kB mmap    0.0170   657.79
Time for 10000 1MB mmaps    0.0217   633.38
```

Even accounting for the reduced amount of memory, it seems to be an unusual given the file is only half the physical memory. Can anyone point to a change to the code or a configuration change which might improve the performance?

We're tried using reads instead of mmaps, and it does make a substantial difference, but doing that would require a substantial change to an existing code base (and mmap is a lot faster than the read on linux).

Comment: Your `total` variable is not used after the assigmnents? It might just be optimized out, so you might not be measuring the right thing.

Comment: Your large `buf` array is never used - perhaps you need to show the definition of your `femmap()` and `femunmap()` functions? A compilable example always helps.

Comment: Running Activity Monitor via Instruments on Mac OS X will probably reveal a significant page-in page-out load.  The MacOS X test system's RAM is too low for a fair comparison.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just don't measure the right thing. I checked the inner part of your test and my version of gcc is able to completely optimize the loop away.

This changes e.g when I declare the `mblock` pointer to be a pointer to `volatile` data. Then the compiler is obliged to perform all side effects on the statement in the loop, in particular to charge it from memory.

So the only conclusions that you may draw from your test are:

- your compiler on MacOS X is not very
  smart
- always check for the assembler that a
  bench mark produces

So if you could redo your test for real, I would be interested in seen the real difference of the two systems with respect to that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is "by design".  According to this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemAdvancedPT/MappingFilesIntoMemory/MappingFilesIntoMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010765-CH2-SW1:

You should not use file mapping in the following situations:

- You want to read a file sequentially
  from start to finish only once.
- The file is several hundred megabytes
  or more in size. (Mapping large files
  fills virtual memory space quickly.
  In addition, your program may not
  have the available space if it has
  been running for a while or its
  memory space is fragmented.)

For large sequential read operations, you are better off disabling disk caching and reading the file into a small memory buffer. See “Cache Files Selectively” for more information.

---

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates the problem:

```
off_t       file_target = off_t(3) << 29; //  1.5GB
const char* path = "B9361194.data";

//  Touch the output file
{
    FILE*       fp = fopen( path, "a");
    fclose(fp);
}

//  Open the output file
FILE*       fp = fopen( path, "rb+");
int         fd = fileno(fp);
off_t       file_physical = 0;
off_t       file_logical = 0;
ftruncate( fd, file_physical );

//  Declare the mapping
off_t       map_start = 0;
off_t       map_count = 0;
char*       map_address = 0;

//  Set up the input buffer.
//  We are just going to write this out until we have written total bytes
size_t      requested = 1024;
char    input[requested];
for ( size_t i = 0; i < requested; ++i ) input[i] = 1;

//  Write the buffer, resizing and mapping as we go.
while ( file_logical < file_target ) {
    //  Figure out how much to write.
    size_t limit = requested;
    if ( ( file_target - file_logical ) < (off_t)limit ) 
        limit = size_t( file_target - file_logical );

    //  If we can't fit the buffer inside the allocation
    //  unmap and grow everything
    if ( file_logical + (off_t)limit > file_physical ) {
        //  Unmap
        if ( map_address ) munmap( map_address, map_count );

        //  Grow the file by 64K
        off_t   new_physical = off_t(1) << 16;  //  64K allocation
        if ( new_physical < (off_t)limit ) new_physical = limit;
        file_physical += new_physical;
        ftruncate( fd, file_physical );

        //  Map the end
        map_count = off_t(1) << 23;    //  8MB
        if ( map_count > file_physical ) map_count = file_physical;
        map_start = file_physical - map_count;
        void* address = mmap( 0, map_count, ( PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ ), MAP_SHARED, fd, map_start );
        // int err = errno;
        // if ( address == MAP_FAILED ) CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL_MESSAGE( strerror(err), 0, errno );
        map_address = reinterpret_cast<char*>( address );
    }

    //  Copy the buffer in
    size_t  offset = size_t(file_logical - map_start);
    memcpy( map_address + offset, input, limit );
    file_logical += limit;
}

//  Clean up
if ( map_address ) munmap( map_address, map_count );
ftruncate( fd, file_logical );
fclose( fp );
```

No idea if and when they will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

My conclusion to the OS X mmap problem is map the entire file and keep it mapped. If you need to expand the file, map more bytes than you need so that you only need to remap occasionally.

You may need to use 64-bit OS X to make this work.